# Android set XML shape as drawable programmatically

Tags: android, xml, resources, drawable, shapes

Hello I have a drawable myshape.xml, it contains a `<shape>` and I cannot set an android:id to shapes.

In my code I want to set the background of a view to this file using

`catAll.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.id......???));`

where myshape.xml does not show up in my R file because it has no id. and I cannot set id to  object.

In my XML I do set the shape by simply typing the drawable resource name. But I need to do this programmatically.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You don't need to get the drawable yourself. Use this instead:

```
catAll.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.myshape);
```

For future reference, if you **do** wish to get the drawable keep in mind that drawables live in the *R.drawable* namespace. So your code would became:

```
getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.myshape);
```

This is akin to what you do in your XML:

```
@drawable/myshape
```

instead of

```
@id/myshape
```

Comment: Pointing out the "R.drawable" namespace was key, thanks K-ballo!

Comment: getDrawable(id) id now depricated.

Answer (score 0):

The question is really old but googles first hit references to this thread.

So `getDrawable(id)` is deprecated.

Short solution (kotlin)

```
yourView.background = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.your_ressource_id)
```

For more, please read this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29146895/4420355